# delete row from datagridview a line is never deleted

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am developing a project where I transfer rows between two datagridvews. I want the rows that I transferred from the upper datagridview to the lower datagridview to be deleted from the upper datagridview. But while some lines are deleted, some are not. I share my codes and images with you.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value == true)

        {
            int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = false;
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

And the other transfer codes from datagridview2 to datagridview1

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value == true)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        }


       // if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
       // {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }
       // }

    }
    SelectedRowTotal();
}
```

[image]

Comment: please avoid hosting images externally

Comment: You have to delete from the end to the beginning.  When you delete row 5 row 6 becomes row 5 and you skip an item.  So use a for loop : for(int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { DataGridViewRow item = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

Comment: Can you help me what should I write for the deletion process? I'm really confused about this.

Comment: please help @jdweng

Comment: Change the Foreach to my For loop.  When you have a list 1,2,3,4,5 and you delete one item you get 1,2,4,5.  A regular foreach will skip 4 and go to 5.  The for each is using index of the array so after deleting the 3 (index 2) the foreach goes to the next after index 3 which is index 4 which is the value 5.  Value 4 gets skipped.

Comment: I wrote this code. but it cleared all rows :( for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
               DataGridViewRow item = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
             dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }

Comment: waiting for support @jdweng

Comment: Which rows do you want to delete?  You need an IF statement with conditions of row that should be deleted.   Right now every row gets deleted.  Your original code had : if (!row.IsNewRow)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);

Comment: I want to delete selected rows

Comment: @jdweng I'm waiting help still

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use two loops? try this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value == true)

        {
            int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = false;
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item.Cells[7].Value.ToString();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(item);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }

}
```

and:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value == true)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item.Cells[7].Value.ToString();

            dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(item);
            dataGridView2.Refresh();
        }
    }
    SelectedRowTotal();
    
}
```

Comment: this code is not working exactly as i want. It does not send all of the lines to be sent below and deletes it without sending it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    for(int i = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataGridViewRow item = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
        if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
            dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```